# Why is the file not found despite the path is in PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
/home/stefan/workspace/git/master-thesis/data
```

set in the pythonpath and some XML files which reside in:

```
/home/stefan/workspace/git/master-thesis/data/semeval/*.xml
```

However, if I try to open these XML files I receive:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ABSA16_Restaurants_Train_SB1_v2.xml'
```

Does this only work for *modules*?

Comment: Pythonpath is searched for python modules/packages, not for general data.

Comment: It's only used for the importing of modules. To avoid hardcoding the path to the data files, you're going to need some sort of config or setup file for your application. Another possibility is to use the path of the currently executing script as the root directory for data path that is relative to it.

Comment: @martineau Thanks! I think I'll go with the relative-path solution!

Comment: Good choice if you can use it because it's relatively easy to implement. You can get the path to the currently executing script from the built-in predefined `__file__` variable (and the directory portion of it using the various `os.path` utility functions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modules are searched on this path, see the [documentation on PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames separated by `os.pathsep` (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

You'll need to provide the full path to `open` in order to find it (granted you don't change the current directory).

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. I really thought that this would simply include all directories. Thank you for the answer!